# Forcing R to create a scatterplot

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I'm a novice R user and trying to create a scatterplot in a workspace in which I had already created some treemaps using the treemap package.  When I enter:

```
plot(XData, YData, type = "p", main="Title", xlab="XData Title", ylab="YData Title")
```

R returns:

```
Warning messages:
1: graphical parameter "type" is obsolete 
2: graphical parameter "type" is obsolete 
3: In rect(xleft, ybottom, xright, ytop, col = col, ...) :
graphical parameter "type" is obsolete
```

I assume the treemap package did something to cause R to automatically use the rect() function instead of simply creating a scatterplot but have no idea how to turn this off.  When I take out the "type" parameter, R returns a jacked-up treemap.  I already tried detach(treemap).  Any help in getting R to create a scatter would be appreciated.

My apologies in advance if the code formatting isn't correct, this is my first time posting.

Comment: Please give a full reproducible example (including treemap) using dummy data or an in-build dataset.

Comment: try this `detach("package:treemap", unload=TRUE)` or just `graphics::plot(XData,...)`

Comment: Thank you both.  agstudy-Thanks for the tip on the graphics package.  Once I used the plot.default() function, R returned a scatter.

Comment: ... which means that XData and YData were not vectors, but have a class. Try str(XData). plot.default() as @Peter suggested is fine for testing, but avoid using it, because it shows that something with you data is not Rish.